# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, database, apache, phpmyadmin, memory-limit

i have this error on phpMyAdmin after an import of .CSV file..

I have try to set memory_limit on -1, this work but is very very slow..

I have try to reinstall with most recent PHP version and with most recent Apache version but the error is the same..

This problem is with phpMyAdmin.. On every folder work fine..
I have try to reinstall phpMyAdmin

Comment: How big of a file is it? My have to read line by line.

Comment: 518Kb (2.200 rows x 75 cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that I solved by deleting the table